# How to send a private message to user on MSTeams?

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I want to send a private message to user. Currently, what I have are:

- user id
- tenant id
- bot

Here is my sample code to try to send message:

```
var address =
{
    channelId: 'msteams',
    user: { id: user.id },
    channelData: {
        tenant: {
            id: "cscportal.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
    },
    bot:
    {
        id: bot.id,
        name: bot.name
    },
    serviceUrl: "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer-client-ss.msg/",
    useAuth: true
}

var msg = new builder.Message().address(address);
msg.text("Hello! This is a sample message.");
msg.textLocale('en-US');
bot.send(msg);
```

My sample code does not work because of something wrong in my address. Can you help me to find a way to send a private message to user?

*Note: I don't have conversation ID*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the user’s unique ID and tenant ID to send a proactive message. Typically, these are obtained from a team context, either by fetching the team roster or when a user interacts with your bot in a channel. Please check documentation on how to [create personal conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#starting-a-personal-conversations). Please also read about [Proactive Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-proactive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).

Here is the source code for Node.js sample for [Proactive Messages](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node/blob/master/src/dialogs/examples/teams/ProactiveMsgTo1to1Dialog.ts).

Comment: What is a "proactive" message ?  These names are random

Comment: Typically, each message that a bot sends to the user directly relates to the user's prior input. In some cases, a bot may need to send the user a message that is not directly related to the current topic of conversation or to the last message the user sent. These types of messages are called proactive messages.([Doc Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-proactive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0))